# What is pandas syntax for lookup based on existing columns + row values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to recreate a bit of a convoluted scenario, but I will do my best to explain it:

1. Create a pandas df1 with two columns: `'Date'` and `'Price'` - *done*
2. I add two new columns: `'rollmax'` and `'rollmin'`, where the `'rollmax'` is an ***8 days rolling*** maximum and `'rollmin'` is a
   rolling minimum. - *done*
3. Now I need to create another column **`'rollmax_date'`** that would get
   populated through a look up rule:

   - for the row n, go to the column `'Price'` and parse through the values
     for the last 8 days and find the maximum, then get the value of the
     corresponding column `'Price'` and put this value in the column  `'rollingmax_date'`.
   - the same logic for the `'rollingmin_date'`, but instead of rolling maximum date, we look for the rolling minimum date.

Now I need to find the previous 8 days max and min for the same rolling window of 8 days that I have already found.

I did the first two and tried the third one, but I'm getting wrong results.
The code below gives me only dates where on the same row `df["Price"]` is the same as  **`df['rollmax']`**, but it doesn't bring all the corresponding dates from `'Date'` to `'rollmax_date'`

```
df['rollmax_date'] = df.loc[(df["Price"] == df.rollmax), 'Date']
```

[This is an image with steps for recreating the lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn7Yh.png)

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image with a text table. That's easier to copy-paste, screen readers can handle it *and* you can easily correct the "Adj Close" heading to "Price".

Comment: `df['rollmax_date'] = df.loc[df['Price'] == df.rollmax]['Date']` perhaps?